# Return back to Activity passing intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Current Activity -> A
I'm passing an intent to go to an activity in a different app(some third party app), when back button is pressed, activity A should be back to foreground. How to make such intent?

Comment: Jist finish the activity

Comment: The activity I'm intending to open is not mine. Ex: Gmail, maps etc.

Comment: This should just work, without having to do anything special, unless the app you are launching handles the BACK button in a different way. What have you tried? What are you seeing?

Comment: @DavidWasser the edge case which I want to cover is. 
-> I launch the the third party activity from myActivity
-> Go to home screen
-> launch the third party activity from recents
-> Now press back button, it goes to home screen and not myActivity from where it's initially launched. 
I know this is expected behavior, but is there a way on back press it goes back to myActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Backstack should keep your A activity unless you add FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flags

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you wrote:

> The edge case which I want to cover is. -> I launch the the third
> party activity from myActivity -> Go to home screen -> launch the
> third party activity from recents -> Now press back button, it goes to
> home screen and not myActivity from where it's initially launched. I
> know this is expected behavior, but is there a way on back press it
> goes back to myActivity.

No. That is not possible. It would only be possible if the `Activity` from the 3rd party app is launched into your own task. You don't have any control over this if the 3rd party app doesn't want to be launched into your task (which is probably the case here).

You can force 3rd party app into a new task (by using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`), but not the other way around.

If you are now using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, you should remove it, but even if you do, this won't guarantee that the 3rd party app's `Activity` will launch into your task.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!